# How to configure tor-arm?

Tags: tor

What is the proper way to configure `arm` command in `tor-arm` package to work on 14.04? Because every time I run `arm` it returns:

```
Connection refused. Is the ControlPort enabled?
```

I didn't happen to come across on some good solution while googling, I found [this](https://gnusam.wordpress.com/2012/12/26/monitor-tor-with-arm/) tutorial but still no luck, I guess I'm missing a point somewhere.

Comment: have you enabled all the necessary ports?

Comment: I dunno what is exactly the port that it requires I use `tor` with Firefox on port `9050` when I run it: `arm -i 127.0.0.1:9050`
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TorCtl/TorCtl.py", line 710, in _loop
    isEvent, reply = self._read_reply()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TorCtl/TorCtl.py", line 885, in _read_reply
    raise ProtocolError("Badly formatted reply line: unknown type %r"%tp)
ProtocolError: Badly formatted reply line: unknown type 'P'
Terminated`

Comment: when I run `arm -i 127.0.0.1:9051` it says connection refused as stated in OP

Comment: In my case the torrc was overwritten and while I added the correct values Tor would not reconnect. I had to restart the tor service also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to configure TOR
For this :
We can find the configuration file at /etc/tor/torrc. It’s owned by root, so we’ll have to sudo to edit it:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/tor/torrc
```

We’ll uncomment the options we need, and set them to the appropriate values, ending up with something like this:

```
ORPort 9001
DirPort 9030
ExitPolicy reject *:*
Nickname trustytohr
RelayBandwidthRate 1 MB
RelayBandwidthBurst 2 MB
AccountingStart month 1 00:00
AccountingMax 100 GB
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0**
```

The most important settings are probably `ORPort`, `DirPort` and `ExitPolicy`

after this restart TOR and run arm

Answer (score 1):

The question is kind of old, but I found myself trying to fix the same issue and what I had to was generate a hashed password with `tor --hash-password password` and uncomment and substitute the **HashedPassword** line found at */etc/tor/torrc*.